# To perform Printer maintenance in Ubuntu, is there an application for several types of printers?

Tags: drivers, software-recommendation, printing, metapackages

To perform Printer maintenance in Ubuntu, is there an application that is available for several types of printers?

I want to get details about *Ink levels* and do *Clean the Printer* and *Align the Cartridges*.

I am concerning that through the drivers and packages found on **Official Ubuntu Repository**.

Comment: What printer?  I think if anything is available it will depend on the make and model.

Comment: Ubuntu means not the Launchpad. And it is a OS that not depend on Hardware Manufacturers. Question is about packages in main Ubuntu repository

Comment: IMHO, it depends on the implementation of the drivers included in Ubuntu and CUPS.

Comment: How to perform it ?

Comment: **it depends**. If your printer drivers doesn't support the characteristic no help we could provide will allow you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Printer maintenance is mainly done via it's driver. Only if the printer manufacturer supported maintenance via their open or closed source Linux drivers we may have access to functions provided. Unfortunately for many printers this is not available.

To view ink levels from many [supported printers](http://libinklevel.sourceforge.net/#supported) there is a command line tool [ink](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/ink) [image: Install ink] using **libinklevel5**.

- [List of supported printers](http://libinklevel.sourceforge.net/#supported).

Answer (score 4):

> **Mtink**

This is a good tool for Measure printer ink levels and do maintenance tasks.

It is for **Epson** printers but also works with **HP** and **Cannon** printers.

[image: Install via the software center]

```
sudo apt-get install mtink
```

[image]